Deployment in progress
I am trying to deploy the react web app using github actions but before that my deployment remains in progress for hours and then give me error. I am just deploying a simple react app and it take so much time. I tried using different regions and back to back facing same issue. Please anyone having idea how to fix this issue?

When I am trying to deploy the react app to Azure it doesn't complete.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. For your best chance to get an answer, you'll need to provide more information. Please edit your question and provide the error produced on one of the failed deployments.

According to the screenshot provided in the question, you seem to be stuck at Microsoft.Web/serverfarmsdue toBadGateway.

This could be due to a backend delay in enabling the Microsoft.Web resource provider.
Retry creating the App Service after few hours.

Configure the GitHub deployment during App Service creation.

Duration creation of NodeJS App Service, navigate to Deployment section=> enable Continuous Deployment=>Select GitHub repository of react project


Enable Basic Authentication and Review+create.


This creates the workflow to deploy the app to Azure using GitHub actions.

My Workflow:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - <appname>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<appname>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_3134D1CCXXXXFAC }}


I have deployed the sample react app to Azure using GitHub actions.

Portal:

